# "Ringed space" in Italian

Tags: translation, mathematics

"Anillado" is the translation in Spanish, but there isn't one appearing for me right now on any Italian dictionary that I use... My university is public so even though I was unenrolled I still get to visit the mathematics community. I have to know this translation!

Comment: If you mean “Ring Network” in italian is “Rete ad anello”

Comment: I think that's this one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringed_space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a mathematical term which, I suppose, is too specialized to be found in common vocabularies.

*Ringed* in English (and *anillado* in Spanish) can be translated with *anellato* or *inanellato* (https://www.wordreference.com/enit/ringed). The first form means more "having ring(s)" or "shaped like a ring" and the second more "enclosed by ring(s)" or "wearing a ring".

If this can help, a space enclosed by two concentric circles (Annulus) is called *corona circolare* (https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_circolare) and *anello* in algebra refers to *ring of sets* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_sets). For what I understand, not being a mathematician, these last definitions have little to do with "ringed space".

I think that the term *spazio anellato/inanellato* can be understood by an Italian mathematician as it is more or less the direct translation from English, but maybe he would be happier without any translation, i.e. "il ringed space".

Comment: I don't wish to downvote, but to be honest these suggestions are not too on-point. This is a very technical term, and it is difficult for a non-mathematician to navigate between the various meaning of "anello" and "spazio" here. I am an (applied) mathematician myself, and I do not know how to translate it. :) Luckily it's full of mathematicians here, and some from the most-fitting branch of it, including our mods...

Answer (score 4):

Even if this question has already an accepted answer, I thought it might be useful to post an answer from direct experience.

When I took a scheme theory class in Pisa in 2010, the Italian expression for "(locally) ringed space" was indeed "spazio (localmente) anellato". As you can see this is also the term used in the Italian [Wikipedia page](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_(matematica)) for schemes.

It is worth mentioning that this indeed has no relation with any kind of "annulus", here ["ring"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) is in the sense of abstract algebra.

Comment: What's the reason of the downvote? Denis is a mathematitian, so it seems to me a suitable person to answer this question.

Comment: My teacher of algebraic geometry was American and the textbook was Hartshorne's. However the language was Italian and the term used was indeed “spazio anellato”.